# Forgot my only administrator account password?

Tags: windows-xp, login, administrator

I am on a XP Professional PC, I only have a administrator account for which I forgot the password. How can I fix this login issue?

I cannot format because I have important data on the system. Steps I tried after googling is from safe mode, logging in with a blank password with administrator account. Let me remind I only have a administrator account, no guest account nor a child account.

Comment: Dear asker, please search your question in SuperUser before asking new one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Linux program called `chntpw` that you can use to reset the password. You can download a boot disk from [here](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). Burn the boot CD image (or use the USB boot image if you have a flash drive), and follow the instructions to select the partition, registry directory, and password reset options.

Once you are finished with the whole process, reboot. You should be able to log in with a blank password.